# I have a project where I need to read file codes from a .sln source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I don't want to open that (.sln) file in Visual Studio environment

I want to use the code in another project

for example
I have a form where I can select a file (browse)
Then select the desired file
In a variable!
Or even a text file
I have the code I want
Then I want to check if the code is clean or not.....
Then show  to the user!

My question is not a duplicate! The previous time has been deleted
Because
They thought I was going to open a project in Visual Studio!

Do you have a solution?

Comment: _I want to check if the code is clean or not_ Please define _clean_.

Comment: clean code... I just want the code to analyze it
For example, variable names are correct
Or the number of lines of functions is less than 1 line

Comment: @Steve do you have solution?